# How to convert nested array to normal array and change types?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

I have the following structure of array:

```
[{Id: Number, Attributes: {Name: String, Age: String, Height: String}}]
```

And I want to convert it into the:

```
[{Id: Number, Name: String, Age: Number, Height: Number}]
```

Also how to convert `"2018-12-12 09:19:40"` to an Date object? While converting the entire array.

How to do this? Using lodash or not.

Comment: @Justcode what for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `map` with spread syntax `...`.

```js
const data = [{Id: 'Number', Attributes: {Name: 'String', Age: 'String', Height: 'String'}}]
const res = data.map(({Attributes, ...rest}) => ({...rest, ...Attributes}))
console.log(res)
```

To convert the data types you could use some nested destructuring.

```js
const data = [{Id: 'Number', Attributes: {Name: 'String', Age: '20', Height: '123'}}]
const res = data.map(({Attributes: {Age, Height, ...attr}, ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest,
  ...attr,
  Age: +Age,
  Height: +Height
}))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: but how to convert data type doing this?

Comment: what about Date type? how to convert to it?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: i have added it to my question

Comment: ok, and what about if i want to also convert data type of 'Id'?

Comment: Are you using mongoose? There is no Id type in plain javascript

Comment: in my example of input array there is 'Id: Number'

Comment: could you answer?

Comment: @Chris K. Sry I am not sure what are you asking, if the id type in input is number it will stay number as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/sfu9kt5h/74/, but there is no ID type in javascript.

Comment: But lets say you just want to convert Id from number to string then you could do this https://jsfiddle.net/sfu9kt5h/75/

Comment: yeah i know it will be a number, but i am asking if i can convert it to string for example, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert an object to an array(change type) you can try Object.entries(); 
In Es2017 There is a property which can be useful in these case, (Object.entries());

```
const cars = {"BMW": 3, "Tesla": 2, "Audi": 5}
const map = new Map(Object.entries(cars));
console.log(map);
```

Hope this helps